# Uitableview infinite scroll hang lag

Tags: swift, uitableview, infinite-scroll

[view the video  of problem here](https://youtu.be/YLr-s6FxZDs)
Im trying to make my infinite scroll work smoothly, before i had it working in a way where when the user reachs a certain item count in the table, it would load the others but while doing the load a Footer Activity indicator would appear, then dissapear and add the next batch of rows... which i kinda found annoying later on.. so i wanned to opmitized it. i want the tableview to initially load 100 items, then when the user is just around row 10 it would start to load the next 100 items and rows... the thing is.. everytime it makes the call.. the uitableview kinda hangs...

I did eliminate some trivial code here like the segmented control and letter buttons.. etc,

//
//  VCrestlist.swift
//  AsyncUITableview

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import Parse


class VCrestlist: UITableViewController{


    let PageSize = 80
    var items:[RestsModel] = []
    var isLoading = false
    var letter = "ALL"
    var online = false
    var loaded = false
    var bigviewforact:UIView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

  @IBOutlet var MyFooterView : UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.MyFooterView.isHidden = true
        createButtons()
        // Load custom Xib RestCell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "RestCell", bundle: nil)
       // register cell identifier with custom Xib RestCell
       self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
       tableView.dataSource = self

        loadSegment(0, size: self.PageSize,argletter:"ALL",online:self.online)
        self.ButtonsScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true


    }



    class DataManager {


        func requestData(_ offset:Int, size:Int,letter:String,online:Bool, listener:@escaping ([RestsModel]) -> ()) {


            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                var letra = ""
                print("el offest es \(offset) y el size es  \(size)")


                if (letter != "") {
                    letra = letter
                } else {

                    letra = "ALL"
                }

                let cart  = Cart.sharedInstance


                    Alamofire.request("https://www.getmedata.com/rests.php", parameters: ["offset": "\(offset)","size":"\(size)","letra":"\(letra)","online":"\(online)"]).authenticate(usingCredential: cart.credential).responseJSON() {

                        response in

                        if(response.result.value != nil) {


                            let jsonObj = JSON(response.result.value!);
                            let rests = jsonObj as JSON

                      // print(jsonObj);

                            //generate items


                                if let restsarray = rests["rests"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {



                                    var arr = [RestsModel]()

                                    //3
                                    for restDict in restsarray {

                                        let restName: String? = restDict["nombre"].stringValue
                                        let restLOGO: String? = restDict["logo"].stringValue
                                        let detURL: String? = restDict["url"].stringValue
                                        let detProvincia: String? = restDict["provincia"].stringValue
                                        let detHorario: String? = restDict["horario"].stringValue
                                        let detDireccion: String? = restDict["direccion"].stringValue
                                        let detTipoComida: String? = restDict["tipo_comida"].stringValue
                                         let detTelefono: String? = restDict["telefono"].stringValue
                                        let detidRest: String? = restDict["id"].stringValue
                                        let detalleDelivery: String? = restDict["alldelivery"].stringValue
                                        let detalleOrderOnline: String? = restDict["orderonline"].stringValue
                                        let detalleReservaOnline: String? = restDict["reservasonline"].stringValue
                                        let dethasSchedule: Bool? = restDict["hasSchedule"].boolValue
                                        let detopenNow: Bool? = restDict["opennow"].boolValue
                                        let detscheduleToday: String? = restDict["scheduleToday"].stringValue
                                        let detscheduleTodayLiteral: String? = restDict["scheduleTodayLiteral"].stringValue
                                        let emp_instagram: String? = restDict["emp_instagram"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_orderonline: String? = restDict["emp_e_orderonline"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_reservasonline: String? = restDict["emp_e_reservasonline"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_kids: String? = restDict["emp_e_kids"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_pickup: String? =  restDict["emp_e_pickup"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_delivery: String? =  restDict["emp_e_delivery"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_wifi: String? =  restDict["emp_e_wifi"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_valet: String? =  restDict["emp_e_valet"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_exterior: String? =  restDict["emp_e_exterior"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_happyhour: String? =  restDict["emp_e_happyhour"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_desayuno: String? =  restDict["emp_e_desayuno"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_fumar: String? =  restDict["emp_e_fumar"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_vinos: String? =  restDict["emp_e_vinos"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_bar: String? =  restDict["emp_e_bar"].stringValue
                                        let emp_e_games: String? =  restDict["emp_e_games"].stringValue

                                        let rest = RestsModel(name: restName!,image:restLOGO!,detailURL:detURL!,provincia:detProvincia!,tipocomida:detTipoComida!,idRest:detidRest!,hasSchedule: dethasSchedule!,scheduleToday: detscheduleToday!,scheduleTodayLiteral: detscheduleTodayLiteral!,openNow: detopenNow!,allDelivery: detalleDelivery!,orderonline: detalleOrderOnline!,reservaonline: detalleReservaOnline!, instagram: emp_instagram!, emp_e_kids: emp_e_kids!, emp_e_pickup: emp_e_pickup!, emp_e_delivery: emp_e_delivery!, emp_e_wifi: emp_e_wifi!, emp_e_valet: emp_e_valet!, emp_e_exterior: emp_e_exterior!, emp_e_happyhour: emp_e_happyhour!, emp_e_desayuno: emp_e_desayuno!, emp_e_fumar: emp_e_fumar!, emp_e_vinos: emp_e_vinos!, emp_e_bar: emp_e_bar!, emp_e_games: emp_e_games!, horario: detHorario!, direccion: detDireccion! ,telefono: detTelefono!)


                                        arr.append(rest)


                                    }

                                    print(arr)

                                    //call listener in main thread
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        listener(arr)
                                    }
                            }




                }
                        }
                }



                ///



                      }
    }


    func loadSegment(_ offset:Int, size:Int,argletter:String,online:Bool) {

        if (self.loaded == false) {
            let act:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)

            bigviewforact.addSubview(act)
            act.center = bigviewforact.center
            self.view.addSubview(bigviewforact)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: bigviewforact)
            act.hidesWhenStopped = true
            act.startAnimating()
            //self.bigviewforact.removeFromSuperview()
            self.loaded = true

        }

        //if (!self.isLoading) {
          //  self.isLoading = true
          //self.MyFooterView.isHidden = (offset==0) ? true : false

            let manager = DataManager()

            manager.requestData(offset, size: size,letter:argletter,online:online,
                listener: {(items:[RestsModel]) -> () in

                    /*
                    Add Rows at indexpath
                    */
                    for item in items {
                        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                        let row = self.items.count
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(row:row,section:0)
                        self.items += [item]
                        self.tableView?.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
                        self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    }

                     self.bigviewforact.removeFromSuperview()
                    self.isLoading = false
                  self.MyFooterView.isHidden = true
                }
            )
       // }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if indexPath.row == items.count-70 {
        loadSegment(items.count, size: PageSize,argletter:self.letter,online:self.online)
        }


    }


    // MARK: Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 85;
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : RestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RestCell

        // Pass data to Cell :) clean the mess at the View Controller ;)
        cell.restData = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.tag = indexPath.row


        return cell
    }




}
```

Comment: You should probably check that you are not already loading before starting a new load. Why is that code commented out? You should also split the code into multiple classes just for the sake of readability. Why don't you pass `json` to `RestsModel.init` intead of parsing it in place? Also, I believe that `Alamofire` calls handlers on the main queue, therefore the parsing is done on the main queue already.

Comment: @Sulthan you are right about the isLoading check.. i did commented out by mistake.. about the json parsing.. well this is some old code :D ... even thought i wasnt checking if loading already.. so it prevents to double load.. i have fix.. but the thing hangs still as soons as it makes the call.. it lags the uitableview for a split second...

Comment: Did you try to just update your items array, and then call `tableView.reloadData` on the main thread ? So, just remove `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and reload the table wherever you call `listener(arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't insert each item into UITableView. Insert all of them together.

```
var indexPathes: [IndexPath] = []
var newItems: [RestsModel] = []
for item in items {
    let row = self.items.count
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row:row,section:0)
    newItems.append(item)
    indexPathes.append(indexPath)
}

self.items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView?.insertRows(at: indexPathes, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: just tried replacing this part of the code and got a SIGABORt on tableview.endUpdates()  ... wierd..

Comment: and really, your solutions makes so much sense.. i was calling the insertRows in the for loop.. :/ which i guess  is a pain to process :lol .. but now the tihing is giving me an error..

Comment: Could you try to do it in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` block?

Comment: and what message you get in console with SIGABORt error?

Comment: tried the whole block with the dispatchque.main.sync block.. still Thread 1: signal SIGABRT , then i tried in the json call part when filling the array ( where i also had a main.sync block but did removed.. so i just added.. i dont get the sigabort.. but nothing displays at the uitable...  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        arr.append(rest)
                                        }

Comment: checking with some breakpoints..  // edit.// just did. if using the main.async { arr.append(rest) . i get 0 values  .. lol

Comment: what will happen if you will call `self.tableView.reloadData` instead of `self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView?.insertRows(at: indexPathes, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164194/discussion-between-lorenzo-gonzalez-and-taras-chernyshenko).